# Are offscreen animations ignored by rendering and CPU?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Just wondering how Cocos manages the CPU cycle and graphics engine for CCSprites that are offscreen, including those in the middle of an animation. If you have many animated sprites going on and off the screen, I could check and stop each animation when it's off the screen then restart it when it is about to come back on, but I'm wondering if this is necessary?

Suppose you had a layer with a bunch of them and you make the layer invisible, but don't stop the sprite animations. Will they still use CPU time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a quick test (good question :) ), in a game where i can slide the screen over a large map that contains images of soldiers performing an 'idle' animation. They continue running when off-screen (I tacked a CCCallFunc in a sequence in a repeat forever, to a simple selector that logs).

I suspect they would also run when the object is not visible. It kind of makes sense, especially for animations. If you look at my use case, if the animation were stopped, it could cause a cognitive disconnect if the user slided the soldier in and out of view, especially when the soldier is doing a walk on the map - he could actually walk-in the view without the user having done any interaction with the screen.

Comment: interesting; so the CPU is likely working on these animations, even if they are offscreen. But I assume the graphics engine is not participating at all unless they are onscreen, right

Comment: @andrewx : new thread i stumbled upon, lots of interesting stuff about GPU, processing cost for sprites, etc.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502586/does-the-visible-property-affect-performance