# Reduce overhead for sprite outside the screen

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

For my game I am working on a 2  player mode where the player can swipe left to see what the other player is doing. Effectively 2 iPhone screens.

My question is, are any sprites, particles outside the screen (I.e. for player 2) being rendered and processed as if they are on screen? If so, is there a way to get cocos2d to handle these differently so that they do not slow down the overall game performance? (fps)

Comment: For example if I set player 2 objects to be invisible when they are offscreen. Will that reduce the overhead? I would like the frame rate for whichever screen the user is viewing to stay at 60fps.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i know to lower overhead is to make the sprite.visible property NO, in which case the draw wont be computed at all. Off-screen sprites will be drawn if they are set as visible. Also, before making any 'FPS' related decision, make certain you verify what you get on real devices. You will find that the simulator falls very short, performance wise.

Comment: Generally speaking Simulator performance is nothing but meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `visible` property to `NO`, it will indeed reduce overhead. If a sprite is outside the screen, it will still draw itself (so yes, you can set it to NO to reduce some overhead). But in any case, regardless of the `visible` property value, all sprites will still consume some memory and such.

If they have animations, they will keep on playing. You can unschedule those sprites and free some more processing.

A question I made regarding this `visible` property may help you: [Does the .visible property affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502586/does-the-visible-property-affect-performance)